# Publishingweb not working in sharepoint foundation

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Microsoft.sharepoint.Publishingweb namespace  not working in sharepoint foundation it is working in sharepoint server so is there any way that is use the namespace in sharepoint foundation

Answer (score 2):

No, since the class `Microsoft.SharePoint.PublishingWeb` is part of the assembly `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing` which is not part of a foundation installation.